# Random Coefficient AR(1) and Kalman filtering

Tags: conditional-expectation, kalman-filter, vector-auto-regression

I am interested in a process such that

\begin{align*}
&x_{t+1}=\rho_{t} x_t+\varepsilon_t, \varepsilon_t\sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_{\varepsilon}^2)\\
&\rho_t=\lambda \rho_{t-1}+(1-\lambda)u_t, u_t\sim U[0, 1]
\end{align*}

where $x_t$ for all $t$ are observable but not $\rho_t$. All parameters are also given (including the variance of $\varepsilon_t$ and $\lambda$) Suppose at time $t$, we want to know $E_tx_{t+1}$, then we must know $E_t\rho_t$ so we have to derive the conditional expectation of $\rho_{t-1}$. Can this problem be solve by the recursive Kalman filtering or any other reference could anyone suggest? I hardly found any useful reference online.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be accounted by using an [Extended Kalman Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Kalman_filter) (EKF), which can be employed when the equations of the dynamics are nonlinear wrt the state variables.

In your case, we can define the state of the system as follows:

$$z_{t} = \begin{bmatrix}
x_t\\
\rho_t
\end{bmatrix}.$$

The dynamics of the system is described by the following equations:

\begin{align*}
&x_{t+1}=\rho_{t} x_t+\varepsilon_t \\
&\rho_{t+1}=\lambda \rho_{t}+(1-\lambda)u_{t}
\end{align*}

where $\varepsilon_t$ and $u_t$ are random processes. The nonlinearity is due to the product $\rho_t x_t$ in the first equation.

The idea behind the EKF is to linearize using the 1st-order Taylor expansion of system dynamics. That is, the equation for the covariance update is:

$$P_{t+1|t} = F_t P_{t|t} F_t^\top + Q_t,$$

where $Q_t$ is the covariance matrix of the disturbances $\varepsilon_t$ and $u_t$  and $F_t$ is the jacobian matrix of the dynamics:

$$F_t = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial x_{t+1}}{\partial x_{t}} & \frac{\partial x_{t+1}}{\partial \rho_{t}}\\
\frac{\partial \rho_{t+1}}{\partial x_{t}} & \frac{\partial \rho_{t+1}}{\partial \rho_{t}}
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\rho_t & x_t \\
0 & \lambda
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

For the correction part, you still use the linear version of the standard KF. Specifically, the measurement matrix is:

$$H_t = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\end{bmatrix},$$

since you measure just $x_t$.

I'm quite sure that the scheme of EKF can be also applied recursively. You just need to use $F_t$ wherever it is needed.